# Pygame not animating sprites

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a chess program and I am working on the user UI. One of the things I am working on is the piece animation. I have two files: My chess Engine (irrelevant for this but I have provided just in case) and my main file. Here they are:

Main File:

```
import pygame as p
import ChessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK',
              'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(
            p.image.load('Chess/Images/' + piece + '.png'), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False

    loadImages()
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()
    playerClicks = []

    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                if sqSelected == (row, col):
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                else:
                    sqSelected = (row, col)
                    playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
                if len(playerClicks) == 2:
                    move = ChessEngine.Move(
                        playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                    print(move.getChessNotation())
                    for i in range(len(validMoves)):
                        if move == validMoves[i]:
                            gs.makeMove(validMoves[i])
                            moveMade = True
                            sqSelected = ()
                            playerClicks = []
                    if not moveMade:
                        playerClicks = [sqSelected]
            elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_z:
                    gs.undoMove()
                    moveMade = True

        if moveMade:
            animateMove(gs.moveLog[-1], screen, gs.board, clock)
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
            moveMade = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    if sqSelected != ():
        r, c = sqSelected
        if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whitetoMove else 'b'):
            s = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            s.set_alpha(100)
            s.fill(p.Color('blue'))
            screen.blit(s, (c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE))
            s.fill(p.Color('yellow'))
            for move in validMoves:
                if move.startRow == r and move.startCol == c:
                    screen.blit(s, (SQ_SIZE*move.endCol, SQ_SIZE*move.endRow))


def drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    drawBoard(screen)
    highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(
                c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(
                    c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    global colors
    dR = move.endRow - move.startRow
    dC = move.endCol - move.startCol
    framesPerSquare = 10
    frameCount = (abs(dR) + abs(dC)) * framesPerSquare
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        r, c = (move.startRow + dR * frame / frameCount,
                move.startCol + dC*frame / frameCount)
        drawBoard(screen)
        drawPieces(screen, board)
        color = colors[(move.endRow + move.endCol) % 2]
        endSquare = p.Rect(move.endCol*SQ_SIZE,
                           move.endRow*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
        p.draw.rect(screen, color, endSquare)
        if move.pieceCaptured != '--':
            screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceCaptured], endSquare)
        screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceMoved], p.Rect(
            c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and my Chess Engine:

```
    def __init__(self):
        # 8x8 2d board, each element has 2 characters.
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.moveFunctions = {'p': self.getPawnMoves,
                              'R': self.getRookMoves, 'N': self.getKnightMoves, 'B': self.getBishopMoves, 'Q': self.getQueenMoves, 'K': self.getKingMoves}

        self.whitetoMove = True
        self.moveLog = []
        self.whiteKingLocation = (7, 4)
        self.blackKingLocation = (0, 4)
        self.checkMate = False
        self.staleMate = False
        self.enpassantPossible = ()
        self.currentCastlingRight = CastleRights(True, True, True, True)
        self.castleRightsLog = [CastleRights(
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bks, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs)]

    def makeMove(self, move):
        self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = "--"
        self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved
        self.moveLog.append(move)
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.whiteKingLocation = (move.endRow, move.endCol)
        elif move.pieceMoved == "bK":
            self.blackKingLocation = (move.endRow, move.endCol)

        if move.isPawnPromotion:
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved[0] + 'Q'

        if move.isEnpassantMove:
            self.board[move.startRow][move.endCol] = '--'

        if move.pieceMoved[1] == 'p' and abs(move.startRow - move.endRow) == 2:
            self.enpassantPossible = (
                (move.startRow + move.endRow)//2, move.startCol)
        else:
            self.enpassantPossible = ()

        if move.isCastleMove:
            if move.endCol - move.startCol == 2:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol -
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1] = '--'
            else:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol +
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-2]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-2] = '--'

        self.updateCastleRights(move)
        self.castleRightsLog.append(CastleRights(
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bks, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs))

    def undoMove(self):
        if len(self.moveLog) != 0:
            move = self.moveLog.pop()
            self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = move.pieceMoved
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.whiteKingLocation = (move.startRow, move.startCol)
        elif move.pieceMoved == "bK":
            self.blackKingLocation = (move.startRow, move.startCol)

        if move.isEnpassantMove:
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = '--'
            self.board[move.startRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
            self.enpassantPossible = (move.endRow, move.endCol)

        if move.pieceMoved[1] == 'p' and abs(move.startRow - move.endRow) == 2:
            self.enpassantPossible = ()

        self.castleRightsLog.pop()
        newRights = self.castleRightsLog[-1]
        self.currentCastlingRight = CastleRights(
            newRights.wks, newRights.bks, newRights.wqs, newRights.bqs)

        if move.isCastleMove:
            if move.endCol - move.startCol == 2:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol +
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-1] = '--'
            else:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol -
                                        2] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1] = '--'

    def updateCastleRights(self, move):
        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks = False
            self.currentCastlingRight.wqs = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'bK':
            self.currentCastlingRight.bks = False
            self.currentCastlingRight.bqs = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'wR':
            if move.startRow == 7:
                if move.startCol == 0:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.wqs = False
                elif move.startCol == 7:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.wks = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'bR':
            if move.startRow == 0:
                if move.startCol == 0:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.bqs = False
                elif move.startCol == 7:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.bks = False

    def getValidMoves(self):
        tempEnpassantPossible = self.enpassantPossible
        tempCastleRights = CastleRights(self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.bks,
                                        self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs)
        moves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
        if self.whitetoMove:
            self.getCastleMoves(
                self.whiteKingLocation[0], self.whiteKingLocation[1], moves)
        else:
            self.getCastleMoves(
                self.blackKingLocation[0], self.blackKingLocation[1], moves)
        for i in range(len(moves)-1, -1, -1):
            self.makeMove(moves[i])
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
            if self.inCheck():
                moves.remove(moves[i])
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
            self.undoMove()
        if len(moves) == 0:
            if self.inCheck():
                self.checkMate = True
            else:
                self.staleMate = True
        else:
            self.checkMate = False
            self.staleMate = False
        self.enpassantPossible = tempEnpassantPossible
        self.currentCastlingRight = tempCastleRights
        return moves

    def inCheck(self):
        if self.whitetoMove:
            return self.squareUnderAttack(self.whiteKingLocation[0], self.whiteKingLocation[1])
        else:
            return self.squareUnderAttack(self.blackKingLocation[0], self.blackKingLocation[1])

    def squareUnderAttack(self, r, c):
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
        oppMoves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
        for move in oppMoves:
            if move.endRow == r and move.endCol == c:
                return True
        return False

    def getAllPossibleMoves(self):
        moves = []
        for r in range(len(self.board)):
            for c in range(len(self.board[r])):
                turn = self.board[r][c][0]
                if (turn == 'w' and self.whitetoMove) or (turn == 'b' and not self.whitetoMove):
                    piece = self.board[r][c][1]
                    self.moveFunctions[piece](r, c, moves)
        return moves

    def getPawnMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.whitetoMove:
            if self.board[r-1][c] == "--":
                moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c), self.board))
                if r == 6 and self.board[r-2][c] == "--":
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-2, c), self.board))
            if c - 1 >= 0:
                if self.board[r-1][c-1][0] == 'b':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c-1), self.board))
                elif (r - 1, c - 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r-1, c-1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

            if c + 1 <= 7:
                if self.board[r-1][c+1][0] == 'b':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c+1), self.board))
                elif (r - 1, c + 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r-1, c+1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

        else:
            if self.board[r+1][c] == "--":
                moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c), self.board))
                if r == 1 and self.board[r+2][c] == '--':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+2, c), self.board))

            if c-1 >= 0:
                if self.board[r+1][c-1][0] == 'w':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c-1), self.board))
                elif (r + 1, c - 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r+1, c-1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

            if c+1 <= 7:
                if self.board[r+1][c+1][0] == 'w':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c+1), self.board))
                elif (r + 1, c + 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r+1, c+1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

    def getRookMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        directions = ((-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1))
        enemyColor = "b" if self.whitetoMove else "w"
        for d in directions:
            for i in range(1, 8):
                endRow = r + d[0] * i
                endCol = c + d[1] * i
                if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                    endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                    if endPiece == "--":
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                    elif endPiece[0] == enemyColor:
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def getKnightMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        knightMoves = ((-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2),
                       (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1))
        allyColor = "w" if self.whitetoMove else "b"
        for m in knightMoves:
            endRow = r + m[0]
            endCol = c + m[1]
            if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                if endPiece[0] != allyColor:
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))

    def getBishopMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        directions = ((-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1))
        enemyColor = "b" if self.whitetoMove else "w"
        for d in directions:
            for i in range(1, 8):
                endRow = r + d[0] * i
                endCol = c + d[1] * i
                if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                    endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                    if endPiece == "--":
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                    elif endPiece[0] == enemyColor:
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def getQueenMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        self.getRookMoves(r, c, moves)
        self.getBishopMoves(r, c, moves)

    def getKingMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        kingMoves = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
                     (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
        allyColor = "w" if self.whitetoMove else "b"
        for i in range(8):
            endRow = r + kingMoves[i][0]
            endCol = c + kingMoves[i][1]
            if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                if endPiece[0] != allyColor:
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))

    def getCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.squareUnderAttack(r, c):
            return
        if (self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.wks) or (not self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.bks):
            self.getKingsideCastleMoves(r, c, moves)
        if (self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.wqs) or (not self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.bqs):
            self.getQueensideCastleMoves(r, c, moves)

    def getKingsideCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.board[r][c+1] == '--' and self.board[r][c+2] == '--':
            if not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c+1) and not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c+2):
                moves.append(
                    Move((r, c), (r, c+2), self.board, isCastleMove=True))

    def getQueensideCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.board[r][c-1] == '--' and self.board[r][c-2] == '--' and self.board[r][c-3] == '--':
            if not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c-1) and not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c-2):
                moves.append(
                    Move((r, c), (r, c-2), self.board, isCastleMove=True))


class CastleRights():
    def __init__(self, wks, bks, wqs, bqs):
        self.wks = wks
        self.bks = bks
        self.wqs = wqs
        self.bqs = bqs


class Move():
    ranksToRows = {"1": 7, "2": 6, "3": 5,
                   "4": 4, "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 0}
    rowsToRanks = {v: k for k, v in ranksToRows.items()}
    filesToCols = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2,
                   "d": 3, "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7}
    colsToFiles = {v: k for k, v in filesToCols.items()}

    def __init__(self, startSq, endSq, board, enpassantPossible=False, isCastleMove=False):
        self.startRow = startSq[0]
        self.startCol = startSq[1]
        self.endRow = endSq[0]
        self.endCol = endSq[1]
        self.pieceMoved = board[self.startRow][self.startCol]
        self.pieceCaptured = board[self.endRow][self.endCol]

        self.isPawnPromotion = (self.pieceMoved == 'wp' and self.endRow == 0) or (
            self.pieceMoved == 'bp' and self.endRow == 7)

        self.isEnpassantMove = enpassantPossible
        if self.isEnpassantMove:
            self.pieceCaptured = 'wp' if self.pieceMoved == 'bp' else 'bp'

        self.isCastleMove = isCastleMove

        self.moveID = self.startRow * 1000 + \
            self.startCol*100 + self.endRow*10 + self.endCol

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Move):
            return self.moveID == other.moveID
        return False

    def getChessNotation(self):
        return self.getRankFile(self.startRow, self.startCol) + self.getRankFile(self.endRow, self.endCol)

    def getRankFile(self, r, c):
        return self.colsToFiles[c] + self.rowsToRanks[r]
```

I am not getting an error, however I am not getting an animation either; just a delay.

I am on a Macbook Air, if that has anything to do with this.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to handle the events in the animation loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

For instance:

```py
def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    # [...]
    
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        pygame.event.pump()

        # [...]

        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```